# Inconsistent string/array formatting in JWT payload

Tags: c#, jwt, token

I am creating JWT's (Json Web Token) using `System.IdentityModel.Token.JWT`

Essentially feeding a bunch of claims into the `WriteToken()` method and getting a token string back.

The problem is that the formatting is inconsistent. If I add a "role" claim with a value, it's formatted as a string. If I add one more "role" claim it's formatted as an array. And the consumer has to do special processing to figure out what it is.

The docs say :

> "For each Claim a JSON pair { 'Claim.Type', 'Claim.Value' } is added. If duplicate claims are found then a { 'Claim.Type', List } will be created to contain the duplicate values."

How can I avoid this and always get an array?

Comment: As docs says when you add second key then it converts to an array, so to always get an array just add a black Claim.Value in the token and handle that while parsing.

Comment: like a dummy value? Yes I thought about that, but it's a kludgy workaround and that value must be considered and removed during parsing. I need another way...